# How to get python to preform a function every (x) seconds?

Tags: python, time, timing

I am learning python, and am trying to make (how original) a disease model, where green balls bounce around and if a red ball touches them, they get infected with the red color.
I am trying to make it so every x seconds, each infected red ball has a probability to die and turn black, but I can't figure out how to do that. I have tried to use pygame's clocks but couldn't figure it out.

here's the die function

```
def die(particle_list):
    for i in particle_list:
        if (i.colour == red) and random.choice([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0])==0:
            i.colour = black
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) method. It will block program execution for the given number of seconds.

I would also like to point out that is better to use random numbers for probablilities like this. In you example your particle has a 1 in 15 chance to die, so you would want to generate a random number from 0 to 1, and i the number is bellow 0.066666667 (1 / 15) the particle will die.

This example will do what you want:

```py
import random

def die(particle_list, death_rate):
    for particle in particle_list:
        if random.random() <= death_rate:
            particle.color = black
```

Comment: Oh cool the probabilities thing is much better, thank you! Wouldn’t having a function with a time.sleep(10) inside the main loop stop the whole from working and then the balls will all stop moving?

Comment: Yes it would, but if you look at @Arshad Ansari's answer, you'll see them describe a concept called concurrency or multithreading which you can use to run a piece of code at the same time as another block within the same program.

Answer (score 0):

If the task of checking the red balls for killing them is suppose to happen without bothering the rest of the process, then I'd suggest that you use a separate thread to check it and perform operation.

Check out the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module in standard library for examples.

Simplest example would be:

```
import threading, time

def checkballs_and_turn_black(balls_data):
   while True:
       time.sleep(10) # sleep for 10 secs
       for ball in balls_data:
           if check_probability(ball):
               ball.set_black()

t = threading.Thread(target=checkballs_and_turn_black, args=(actual_balls_data,))
t.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved the issue. I didn't yet firgure out how multithreading works, but I will look into tutorials for that as that seems easier than what I came up with. I did this:

```
d = 0
def day_counter():
    global day_count, timelist
        time = int(pg.time.get_ticks()/1000)
        if time not in timelist:
            timelist.append(time)
            d = True
        if timelist[-1]%(seconds_in_a_day) == 0 and d:
            day_count += 1
            d = False
            e = True
```

so that the constant e becomes True every in-game day (which ticks every (seconds_in_a_day) seconds) Then, I used the constant e to regulate how often the other time based functions happen, like this:

```
def die(particle_list):
    global sick_count,dead_count,e
    for i in particle_list:
        if i.colour == red and e:
            if r.random() < death_rate:
                i.colour = black
                sick_count -= 1
                dead_count += 1
    e = False
```

<sub>*Answer added on behalf of OP.*</sub>